# Option To AutoFormat Query Syntax in SSMS 2005 or 2008?

Tags: sql

In TOAD (for SQL or Oracle), there is a simple AUTOFORMAT button that will nicely format your query - I couldn't find that option in SSMS 2005, but was advised by a co-worker that it was available in SSMS 2008.  I am unable to locate the option there either.

This is VERY helpful when pasting a query from another source.

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 2):

SSMS 2008 has a feature called intellisense, which is really an auto-complete tool. It only works when connected to a 2008+ server, as well. There is no built in code formatter/beautifier.

You can get this add in, though: http://www.dpriver.com/products/sqlpp/ssms_index.php. It does exactly that.

If you do not register it, it will pop up a dialog from time to time asking if you would like to register, but the functionality remains unrestricted forever.

Highly recommended tool!

Comment: Well that just sucks now, doesn't it?  You'd think by now that MS would have realized that this is an important feature.  While that add-in certainly appears to do what I'm looking to do (and I will give it a try), I don't have the authority to get it licensed.  TOAD I can get licensed & installed.  I would have thought that someone would have made a small add-in (for free) that adds this capability - that's part of what I like about TOAD, it already comes with the function (only the licensed versions though, not the Freeware version).

Thanks for the link thouh   :)

Answer (score 1):

I, personally, use the [Poor Man's T-SQL Formatter](http://architectshack.com/PoorMansTSqlFormatter.ashx#Download_5).  It's freeware and no registration is required.

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is a little old but you can download SSMS Tools pack (http://ssmstoolspack.com/) which is free for 2008 and 2008 R2. There is licensing needed for 2012. I do not use SSMS without installing these tools with it. It has many features including what your looking for. It is called "Text Format" and you can capitalize keywords by pressing CNTRL+G when you need it. I particularly find the SQL History to be fantastic.